# how to inherit point of sale template properly and add new data to display in point of sale session in odoo 12

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

Hi I had tried to inherit the pos.xml in the point of sale module I want to display a new data just below the Total and Taxes

[image]

I don't know what im doing wrong

here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="attempt_inherit_pos_template" inherit_id="point_of_sale.template">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='subentry']" position="replace">
                <div class='new_subentry'>Additional Discount: </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I added `"qweb" : ["static/src/xml/attempt_inherit_pos_qweb.xml",],` this in my manifest file

i can't see any changes in the POS session screen

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [template inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/qweb.html#template-inheritance) to alter `OrderWidget` template.

Change the content of `attempt_inherit_pos_qweb.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="OrderWidget">
        <!--         Taxes selector -->
        <t t-jquery="div.subentry" t-operation="after">
            <!-- Your xml code here -->
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: so what im doing wrong is that i surround my template tag with data and odoo tag which i think is not necessary thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Wrongly inherited pos template,

```
<template id="Orderline_cust" inherit_id="point_of_sale.Orderline">
    <!-- Xpath -->
</template>
```

Thanks